# Mask IP Address Android Device

Tags: privacy, tor

How would I anonymize my Android device and it's IP address? I don't want to be rooted as well, using a GS4.

Comment: There's three related questions on the matter tagged with [tag:tor] - have you looked at those as well?

Comment: Who are you trying to be anonymous from?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **VPN application**, which usually works with no root access but approaches what you're looking for. In addition, you can use [Hideman VPN.](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.hideman) Also, one of your question tags are *Tor.* You can use [Tor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.torproject.android), but only the [Orweb](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=info.guardianproject.browser) Browser will stay anoynmous. Without root, it's **not** your device that's anonymous.

Comment: Hideman looks good, but probably not going to pay. Thanks though!